# pass data to another component vuejs 3 and composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-api

I´m trying to send data to my component table when i clicked a button. My another component should fill a table with data received. i´m using composition API. To try this i´m building this code:

in my table component:

```
export default {
        name: 'nAsignedCalls',    
        props: { registers: Object },

        setup() {
            return {
            }
        }
}
```

and in my `template` i have a `v-for` that i check it´s ok, sending static data:

```
<template v-for="item of registers">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="assign_register" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"></td>
                    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.name }} </td>
                    <td>{{ item.address }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.province }} </td>
                    <td>{{ item.phone }} </td>
```

i said that i check it with statics data:

in my parent component i did:

```
var data = {
                    "address":"CALLE CALLEJAS, 8",
                    "city":"PURULLENA",
                    "cp":"18519",
                    "created_at": "null",
                    "id":"895",
                    "mobile_phone":"null",
                    "name":"Aguilera Muriel Fatimas",
                    "phone":"958.690.236",
                    "province":"GRANADA",
                    "source":"",
                    "updated_at":"2021-11-05T07:35:30.000000Z",
                  }
const registers = reactive({data})
return {
   registers
}
```

result, my table it´s filled.

but when i´m using axios... it´s always empty. I created a composable with function to get my data sending from my parent component, parameter to create query in my API with laravel. From my API i receive my data how my data object but with 160 element

```
Proxy(Array) {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}, 7: {…}, 8: {…}, 9: {…}, 10: {…}, 11: {…}, 12: {…}, 13: {…}, 14: {…}, 15: {…}, 16: {…}, 17: {…}, 18: {…}, 19: {…}, 20: {…}, 21: {…}, 22: {…}, 23: {…}, 24: {…}, 25: {…}, 26: {…}, 27: {…}, 28: {…}, 29: {…}, 30: {…}, 31: {…}, 32: {…}, 33: {…}, 34: {…}, 35: {…}, 36: {…}, 37: {…}, 38: {…}, 39: {…}, 40: {…}, 41: {…}, 42: {…}, 43: {…}, 44: {…}, 45: {…}, 46: {…}, 47: {…}, 48: {…}, 49: {…}, 50: {…}, 51: {…}, 52: {…}, 53: {…}, 54: {…}, 55: {…}, 56: {…}, 57: {…}, 58: {…}, 59: {…}, 60: {…}, 61: {…}, 62: {…}, 63: {…}, 64: {…}, 65: {…}, 66: {…}, 67: {…}, 68: {…}, 69: {…}, 70: {…}, 71: {…}, 72: {…}, 73: {…}, 74: {…}, 75: {…}, 76: {…}, 77: {…}, 78: {…}, 79: {…}, 80: {…}, 81: {…}, 82: {…}, 83: {…}, 84: {…}, 85: {…}, 86: {…}, 87: {…}, 88: {…}, 89: {…}, 90: {…}, 91: {…}, 92: {…}, 93: {…}, 94: {…}, 95: {…}, 96: {…}, 97: {…}, 98: {…}, 99: {…}, …}
```

if i don´t use static data, how i said, i´m using this function to send data to my composable and assign data to my reactive variable.

```
const fetchData = async (param_search) => {
                address = document.getElementById("address").value
                if( address != "" ) {
                    param_search["parameter"] = "address";
                    param_search["value"] = address;
                }

                city = document.getElementById("city").value
                if( city != "" ) {
                    param_search["parameter"] = "city";
                    param_search["value"] = city;
                }

                cp = document.getElementById("postal_code").value
                if( cp != "" ) {
                    param_search["parameter"] = "cp";
                    param_search["value"] = cp
                }

            registers.value = await getRegisters(toRef(param_search,'param_search'))
            console.log(registers.value)
            //emit('submit',registers.value);
        }
```

and in return i have:

```
return {
      //message,
      //showMessage,
      //count,
      fetchData,
      registers,
      //submit
      //increment,
}
```

i´m thinking that i need a personaliced event to send this data to my component table, but when i send static data, it´s not necessary... I don´t know

to add my data to my component table i´m doing this:

```
<div id="app5">
    <nAsignedCalls :registers="registers"></nAsignedCalls>
</div>
```

but never arrive my data, this it´s my problem. When it´s statics yes, but if i want this data to be send when i click my button, never arrive to my table component... What i´m doing wrong?

**UPDATED**

i´m building a personaliced event, and now console.log() returned this:

```
app.js:7203 [Vue warn]: Extraneous non-emits event listeners (submit) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. If the listener is intended to be a component custom event listener only, declare it using the "emits" option. 
  at <NAsignedCalls onSubmit=fn<submit> registers= (160) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …] > 
  at <FormTelemarketing> 
  at <App>
```

i´m building my event so:

in parent:

```
setup(ctx, {emit}) {
            const emits = defineEmits(["submit"])
```

in my function that call composable:

```
registers.value = await getRegisters(toRef(param_search,'param_search'))
                console.log(registers.value)
                emit('submit',registers.value);
```

**updated 2**

[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-danny-s0jhmo?file=/src/components/roomBooss/nasignedCalls.vue)

Comment: You asked this question 4 times, in different forms. I told you the first time: use codesandbox to show the app. If you do that, we can show you how to add a store to it, which can be used to share data between any components in your app.

Comment: ^ This. Also, as mentioned in the previous questions, you need to take a look at what api returns, as this is something you never fully showed and it's possible that you jsut handled it the wrong way. This mocked data `const registers = reactive({data})` is NOT identical to api response. There is an object with data key in one case and and array in another. It's unknown what's the content of the array. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary, otherwise the question violates SO rules

Comment: @tao i´m sorry for incoveniences... But i´m desperate i´m working for 2 weeks
 in this and i can´t solve... i´m reading all documentations and i can´t solve... for this i´m here. I can´t create a reproducible example and i don´t know to do. I´m sorry for being a newbie and ask so much

Comment: All you need to do is install codesandbox package globally on your machine and run `codesandbox ./` in the root of your project. You'll need to create an account on codesandbox. It's quite simple. The example doesn't have to work, we don't need the backend, we can mock it with some functions. But I need to see your components and your `package.json` to be able to help.

Comment: @tao thabks for your response. i´m trying to upload mi codesandbox, but in free count, return this message my VScode [error] Something went wrong while uploading the file. I´m reading that it´s for node modules folders... My proyect it´s laravel

Comment: Then create a new vue app in codesandbox, make sure installed vue matches the version you're using in your project and copy/paste the two components (the parent one and the child one) in the components folder. I'll take it from there.

Comment: @tao i updated my question in updated 2 with my codesandbox. I hope that now it´s a valid question

Comment: `:registers="registers"` [works fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-lichterman-xeu56f?file=/src/components/roomBooss/asignedCalls.vue). You had a lot of other problems (e.g: passing array and expecting object, `item of registers` instead of `item in registers` [read the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for)). I simplified the form usage (use `v-model`!) and replaced your server call with a `Promise.resolve()`. The gist of it: you should go through the basics of Vue before taking on a project of this size. The free modules of vue mastery would definitely help.